# What are these certificates and where are they coming from?

Tags: ssl, azure, ssl-certificate

We have an Azure web role deployed that uses HTTPS. We upload a certificate to azure and shortly after the portal refreshes and two more certificate appear. This is not a wild cart certificate and maybe this is standard behavior, but I haven't seen it before.

**The original certificate is named something like:**

subdomain.domain.com

**The three certificates that appear are named like so:**

VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5

Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority

VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3

Are the 3 certificates I mentioned normally generated or is this an issue I should be looking into?

We have a similar deployment that has an ssl, but does not generate these extra certificates. This is what triggered our concern and has me asking why ...?

Comment: SSL certs have authentication chains - Your cert will be signed by another cert which is itself signed by yet another cert etc.... and so on, until you reach a root cert, which is hardcoded into your browser/ssl infrastructure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enabled HTTPS endpoint in any web application and bind SSL certificate to it, the certificate bind to HTTPS endpoint is could be a single certificate or it could be a chain and 
it is depend on several factors as below:

1. When the certificate is created as self signed ROOT then it will have only one certificate in the chain. This certificate can not be validated to have SSL tunnel because there is no other part to verify it and that why it is called self signed root
2. When you buy certificate from a reputed CA (Certificate Authority) in almost all cases you will get 3 (or more) certificates:

   2.1. Root Certificate : This certificate is helps to create a SSL tunnel between two machines using PKI security Infrastructure.

   2.2. Intermediate Certificate -> This is to create a chain with multiple certs as if needed

   2.3. Domain Certificate -> This is for your *.domainname.com  or domainname.com

Here is an example of chained SSL certificate at https://mail.google.com

[image]

And all of these certificate are chained into one single PFX (if private key embedded into certs) or CER (without any Private Key) so when you deploy only ONE PFX cert, you see the chain is open and all certificates are listed.

If you browser your url  and open the certificate view through browser, you will see exactly same chain as you could see in your portal and you can also verify the certificate thumbprint as well to match.